# Point-in-time recovery of Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Is there a simple solution for point-in-time recovery of a Google Cloud Storage bucket (given that object versioning is enabled)? Something similar to [S3 PIT Restore](https://github.com/angeloc/s3-pit-restore)?

I have a webapp with data (Google Cloud SQL) and files (Google Cloud Storage), where I would like to be able to restore the state at a specific point in time. Cloud SQL offers this natively, and the recovery can even be done from the Cloud Console.

Comment: AFAIK, no, you need to do it by yourselves

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?